# How to fake a path with mod_rewrite? Basically how to serve a flat file on a specific url path using mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

It's been awhile since I've used *mod_rewrite* so I am hoping somebody can shed some light on this quickly.

Basically, I have a flat dynamic PHP file, call it *myForm.php*. I need to serve this file whenever a request is made on the domain at the path *h.t.t.tp://mydomain.com/mylong/uri/contact/path*. If a user goes to that location I need my apache server to serve the *myForm.php* file, and this of course should be oblivious to the user. They would still see */mylong/uri/contact/path* as their location address, but the file being served is from the webroot folder or some other location and called *myForm.php*.

This is easily possible using *mod_rewrite* correct?

Something like:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^/mylong/uri/contact/path$  /myForm.php [PT]
```

Does that work? Taken from:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html

Thanks in advance to anyone who can confirm and provide a great answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove leading slash from `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^mylong/uri/contact/path/?$ /myForm.php [L,NC]
```

`.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.